# shopping cart: need to output ordered items

Tags: php, shopping-cart

The other page that is the index page shows the catalog of the pizzashop. Each pizza is a hyperlink that passes the id to this page. 
The core of my question is in the code that starts with the foreach loop. I would like to simply read out of the database based on the SELECT query at hand.
I know it is weird to put the query IN the loop but for now it is the only way I figured out how to loop through all the ids that are in the SESSION array.
I tried many things to output the return that the query is supposed to give, I fiddled around with the mysqli_stmt thing, all giving me numerous types of errors.

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'pizza_sc_fns.php';
require 'header.php';

@$pizzaId = $_GET['pizza_id'];



if (!isset($_SESSION['order']))
{
    $_SESSION['order'] = array();
    $_SESSION['items'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['totalprice'] = 0.00;
}
if (isset ($_SESSION['order'][$pizzaId]))
{
    echo $_SESSION['order'][$pizzaId]++;
    echo "\$_SESSION['order'][\$pizzaId] is SET \n";
}
else 
{
    echo $_SESSION['order'][$pizzaId] = 1;
}

$conn = connect2db();

foreach ($_SESSION['order'] as $pizzaItem)
{
    $query = "SELECT pizza_name FROM pizzas WHERE pizza_id = $pizzaItem";
    $res = @$conn->query($query);
    echo $res->fetch_assoc(); 
    echo "<hr />";

    //$query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM pizzas WHERE pizza_id=$pizzaItem");
    //echo var_dump($query)."<br />";
    //$stmt_exec = mysqli_stmt_fetch($query);
    //print $pizzaItem."<br />";
}


?>

<a href="logout.php"> Destroy session >> </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to use a loop but you don't need to run the query for every iteration. You can use the [in](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/sql/tutorial_mysql_in_and_between.php3) clause.

Your code would be something like

```
$query = 'Select pizza_name from pizzas where id in (';

foreach($_SESSION['order'] as $pizza_id) {
    $query.= mysql_real_escape_string($pizza_id).', ';
}
$query= substr($query, 0, -2); //Get rid of the trailing comma and space
$query .= ')';
```

And you can run the query.

I would recommend that you use prepared statements though I'm not sure how to use them for an in statement.

Comment: looks interesting. Never crossed my mind you could use a loop this way. It's not printing the result of the query yet but that probably has to do with the statement that needs some further tweaking just as you mentioned

Comment: For the sake of completion: `$query= substr($query, 0, -2); ` did the trick, since we need to skip the parenthesis at the end.

Comment: Actually it was the space I'd forgotten I'd used them. I'll update my code.